# silverlight The type exists in both and DataContractSurrogates

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using silverlight 4 with ria serivces ..
I got an error said :

The type 'eLab.Web.SessionsHWFile' exists in both 'eLab.Web.dll' and 'DataContractSurrogates_c96b3601-cd13-4049-93bb-e7b3f59a4fd9'

where eLab.Web is the aspx web project that hosts the silverlight project, and SessionsHWFile is an edmx entity ,it's not a real table in DB, it's VIEW. I dragged a grid from the data source and doped it in XAML user control, and used a query to get the data from stored procedure in DB, but I'm getting the above error when I debug the code and expand the results view :
[image]
<sub>(source: [0zz0.com](http://www10.0zz0.com/2010/07/26/22/244157379.jpg))</sub>

I did this ,adding a view and getting the results from SP in DB, like a million time and nothing happened until this time ..

Comment: in your GetHWFilesForStudent, what are you returning?

Comment: also, for kicks, delete the EDMS and rebuild it using a different namespace.

Comment: thanx @AlvinfromDiaspar, in GetHWFilesForStudent I'm returning a table of type SessionHWFile .

Answer (score 0):

**I think I knew were the problem is ..
I discovered that you can't name two "riaControls:DomainDataSource" with the same Name, even if they're int different xaml pages.

Honestly I don't know why yet, but that's how I fixed the problem ..

Just change the Name property of the "riaControls:DomainDataSource" ...**