# Silverlight Entity Framework DataContractSurrogate Error

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, datacontractsurrogate

I'm receiving a database connection timeout error when my Domain Service is called to return an Entity Framework object.  I'm using Silverlight 4 with Visual Studio 2010.

The initial error is trapped on the Silverlight client side after the EntityQuery Load operation is executed and looks like this:

```
“An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for    details. 
InnerException message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.”
```

I initially thought there might be an error with the SQL Server database, since the error just seemed to suddenly appear, but I found an error I've tracked down deeper in the Domain Service class which looks like this:

```
Function evaluation timed out.
The type 'MyProject.Web.Models.MyCustomEntity' exists in both 'MyProject.Web.dll' and   'DataContractSurrogates_cfc4b316-5204-4fc6-830c-d91c6fc0b24b'
```

This post had a similar error, but their resolution doesn't help me:
[silverlight The type exists in both and DataContractSurrogates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339476/silverlight-the-type-exists-in-both-and-datacontractsurrogates)

I'm kind of at a loss for explaining this and would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem by setting the RIA domain service timeout to a value of 5 minutes (though the query returns much faster than the default timeout).

Still not sure why I got the particular error I did get.  And not sure why the query seemed to timeout.  It is a small query that returns almost instantly.

I found that this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-change-the-request-timeout-for-wcf-ria-services.aspx) had an easy to follow explanation of how to set the request timeout for the domain service:

[Solution was increase RIA domain service timeout:](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/228161.aspx)